# File write issue for user which is in Administrator group in Windows 2019 Server

Tags: administration, windows-server-2019

In Windows Server 2019, the DotNet console application which run using a user which in Administrator Group  can't access file from C:\Inetpub and can't write file in other directory.
Throwing below errors:
Error: Failed to load message file c:\Inetpub
Error: File written to D:\Logs\

If I login in the Server using that service user, to write file or delete file, it is displays a prompt that provides the option to permit or deny the elevation of privilege.
[image]
Stackoverflow shows a solution which says to Disable UAC for administrators group.
But the QA team reject this solution as it needs change in policy.

Please share any other solution which can be implemented in the application.